# how do I find records that one has a negitive value and the other the same positive value

Tags: sql, t-sql

how do I find records that one has a negitive value and the other the same positive value.
I have tried this and things like it but they are not working.

```
 where [Check_Number]=[Check_Number] and Payment_Amount = ([payment_amount]/-1)
```

Comment: Can you add some examples of the data you are trying to extract?

Comment: I am voting to close this question.  There is not enough information to attempt to answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
where a.check_Number + b.check_number = 0 and a.check_number < 0
```

Or, are the two fields payment_amount and check_number?

```
where payment_amount = - check_number and check_number < 0
```

Maybe something like this?

```
select r1.check_number, r1.payment_amount, r2.check_number, r2.payment_amount
from records r1 join
     records r2
     on r1.check_number = r2.check_number and
        r1.payment_amount = - r2.payment_amount
```

Comment: I think this is more where a.Payment_Amount + b.Payment_Amount = 0 and a.Payment_Amount < 0

Comment: Its the payment amount that Im looking for. there are a lot of records with the same check # and I need to find records that have the same +- amount field so I can back them out of a report.

Comment: I dont think your approach is very good. If it is possible that you will have several identical payment amounts (for example 3 purchases for 100$ and respectively 3 checks for 100$) then your report will have 9 entries - instead of 300$ revenue you will get 900$. Better way to check payment ID (they should coinside with corresponding check ID and be uniq for your entire system)

Comment: @Nogard . . . Given that your comment is about twice a long as the original question, it is really hard to judge the merits of the solution.  I should've known been than to answer this . . . I originally thought it was a simple question about arithmetic.

Comment: its to find the mistakes and back them out of reporting. That a check number is put in for 100 then its voided and backed out with a -100 and a new check writen. I need to back those 2 records out. I can not use just check # since it can be used for other records that are right.

Comment: @GordonLinoff actually my comment was towards OP, not your solution as it is perfect for what was asked. I really meant no offence

Comment: @user2022883 but what if check is for buying product A and payment is for product B? Equal sums dont mean equal products/services... but dont want to persist, Gordons answers is very close to what you need